# SQL CLR Trigger, How to make an assembly trusted due to transparent code call critical code?

Tags: c#, sql-server, security, sqlclr

I have dived into researching the SQL CLR. Unfortunately, my first example has problem with **transparent code call to security code**.

The point is my SQL CLR Trigger is treated as transparent code. And in trigger, I use Quartz to call to Quartz Windows service :

```
var properties = new NameValueCollection();
properties["quartz.scheduler.instanceName"] = "ServerScheduler";

properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy"] = "true";
properties["quartz.scheduler.proxy.address"] = string.Format("tcp://{0}:{1}/{2}", "localhost", "555",
                "QuartzScheduler");

var schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory(properties);

IScheduler scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
```

Error:

> (135,1): SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider: Msg 6522, Level 16,
>   State 1, Procedure AfterMarketSessionInserted, Line 1 A .NET Framework
>   error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate
>   "AfterMarketSessionInserted":  System.MethodAccessException: **Attempt
>   by security transparent method**
>   *'.Database.Triggers.MarketSessionTriggers.AfterMarketSessionInserted()'*
>   **to access security critical method** *'Quartz.Impl.StdSchedulerFactory..ctor(System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection)'*
>   **failed.**
>
> Assembly 'Database, Version=1.0.5275.15169, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is partially trusted, which causes the CLR to
>   make it entirely security transparent regardless of any transparency
>   annotations in the assembly itself.  **In order to access security
>   critical code, this assembly must be fully trusted.**
>   System.MethodAccessException:     at
>   Database.Triggers.FinancialMarketSessionTriggers.AfterFinancialMarketSessionInserted()
>
> ### --------------

Why the SQL CLR Trigger code is considered as transparent code and trusted partially?

How to make SQL CLR Trigger code not a transparent code or make it trusted **fully**?

I'm open to suggesstions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why is SQLCLR code only trusted partially?

By default, CLR code running inside of SQL Server (i.e. "SQLCLR") is highly restricted so as to not degrade security or stability of SQL Server.

> How do you make SQLCLR fully trusted?

What the CLR code within an Assembly can do is controlled (mostly) by the `PERMISSION_SET` property of each Assembly. If you do not specify a `PERMISSION_SET` when loading the Assembly via `CREATE ASSEMBLY`, the default will be `SAFE` which is the most restricted and *not* fully trusted. In order for the CLR code to be able to reach outside of SQL Server (to the network, file system, OS, etc.) you would need to set the Assembly to at least `EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, but this is still not **fully** trusted.  In order to be considered **fully trusted** you need to set the Assembly to `UNSAFE`.

In order to set any Assembly to either `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` or `UNSAFE`, you need to do one of the following:

- Sign the Assembly with a password, create an Asymmetric Key from the Assembly, create a Login from the Asymmetric Key, grant the Login the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` permission. This is the preferred method.
- Set the database containing the Assembly to `TRUSTWORTHY = ON`. This assumes that the owner of the database has the `UNSAFE ASSEMBLY` server-level permission (which is typically the case). While this option is quicker / easier, it is not preferred due to `TRUSTWORTHY = ON` being a [fairly wide-open security hole](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/12/30/please-please-please-stop-using-impersonation-execute-as/).

If you want a more detailed look at SQLCLR security, especially in relation to how restricted `SAFE` Assemblies are, check out this [article](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/steps/stairway-to-sqlclr-level-3-security-general-and-safe-assemblies) that I wrote on SQL Server Central.

Answer (score 0):

Some additional information:  if you choose the preferred method of signing the assembly and creating an asymetric key, see this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345106(v=sql.120).aspx)

The SQL snippet below is from the above-mentioned article.  In the master database create the key and login:

```
USE master; 
GO  

CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'C:\MyDBApp\SQLCLRTest.dll';   
CREATE LOGIN SQLCLRTestLogin FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY SQLCLRTestKey ;  
GRANT UNSAFE ASSEMBLY TO SQLCLRTestLogin ;
GO
```

Then create the assembly:

```
CREATE ASSEMBLY SQLCLRTest
FROM 'C:\MyDBApp\SQLCLRTest.dll'
WITH PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE;
```