# Deserialization in a CLR Function fails

Tags: c#, t-sql, sqlclr

I have written some routines for the phonetic conversion of a text in C#. These routines require a bunch aof defined rules for the conversion (search-string/replace-string). The idea was to store thes rules as an embedded ressource within the assembly and then read the rules from it. The starting point for the the deserialization is as follows

```
public static phonet42n.Core.Rules Deserialize(phonet42n.Core.Rules.Ressources ressource)
{
    string ressourceName;
    phonet42n.Core.Rules returnValue;
    System.Xml.XmlReader reader;
    System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer;
    phonet42n.Core.SerializableRules serializeableRules;

    returnValue = new phonet42n.Core.Rules();

    switch (ressource)
    {
        case Ressources.German_01:
            ressourceName = RESSOURCE_XML_GERMAN_01;
            break;
        case Ressources.German_02:
            ressourceName = RESSOURCE_XML_GERMAN_02;
            break;
        default:
            ressourceName = RESSOURCE_XML_GERMAN_01;
            break;
    }

    using (Stream stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(ressourceName))
    {
        using (reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create(stream))
        {
            xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(phonet42n.Core.SerializableRules));
            serializeableRules = (phonet42n.Core.SerializableRules)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(reader);
        }
    }

    foreach (phonet42n.Core.Rule entry in serializeableRules.Rules)
    {
        if (entry.SearchString != null && entry.SearchString.Length > 0)
        {
            returnValue.Add(entry.Index, entry);
        }
    }
    return returnValue;
}
```

The application works fine when executed in an regular executable.

When executing the registered function in SQL Server I get the following error:

```
SELECT [dbo].[Phonet42n]('mayer', 1)
```

produces...

> Meldung 6522, Ebene 16, Status 1, Zeile 22
>   .NET Framework-Fehler beim Ausführen der benutzerdefinierten Routine oder des benutzerdefinierten Aggregats 'Phonet42n': 
>   System.InvalidOperationException: Fehler im XML-Dokument (3,4). ---> System.MethodAccessException: Fehler beim Versuch der Methode "Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read8_SerializableRules(Boolean, Boolean)", auf Methode "phonet42n.Core.Rule..ctor()" zuzugreifen.
>   System.MethodAccessException: 
>   bei System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
>   bei System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   bei System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
>   bei System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
>   bei System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes)
>   bei System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture)
>   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read8_SerializableRules(Boolean isNullable, Boolean checkType)
>   bei Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read19_Rules()
>   System.InvalidOperationException: 
>   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
>   bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader)
>   bei phonet42n.Core.Rules.Deserialize(Ressources ressource)
>   bei phonet42n.Core.Rules..ctor(Ressources ressource, Characters characters)
>   bei phonet42n.Core.HashTable..ctor(Ressources ressource)
>   bei phonet42n.Core.Match..ctor(Re...

Any idea?

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24167712/4684493) help?

Comment: Why embed the rules as a resource? Why not just place them in a separate assembly?

Comment: The `System.MethodAccessException` is the interesting part. The serializer tries to access the default constructor of `phonet42n.Core.Rule..ctor()` which it can't access. Possible it's marked as internal, only a parametrized constructor is available or something similar?

Comment: If access the resources is considered to be dynamic assembly loading, then this isn't allowed in SQLCLR. And while it _might_ work if the Assembly is set to `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE` (noted in my answer that @Hintham linked to), that seems far from ideal given that placing these same rules in another Assembly that you load first and reference from this Assembly will allow for both to be set to `SAFE`.

Comment: Well, embedding the ressource in the same assembly was my first shot and I thought it would be straight forward. I tried to register the assembly with `PERMISSION_SET = UNSAFE`. This would work but  - as stutzky said: it is far from ideal. Placing the rules in another assembly would work with `PERSMISSION_SET = SAFE`? What about signing the assembly? I found a thread somewhere suggesting that. Thx anyway for your comments!

Comment: Marcus: It is a good idea in any case to sign the Assembly. However, I don't think that will change anything here. But no reason not to try it.

Comment: I got in the meantime :D But I cannot say, yet, what exactly was the clue. Probably a mixture of several issues. I signed the assemblies, created an assymmetric login/key, splitted the assemblies and infact - as mentioned by Adweaenyth - the class rule did not hav a public paramterless default constructor. Thanks so far! I will give an update on this tomorrow

Comment: Marcus: the signing / Asymmetric Key / Login shouldn't have had any impact here. The lack of parameterless default constructor might have been the issue. You should be able to take that out (make no other changes) and see if the problem comes back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever there are security exceptions, you can first try setting the Assembly to `PERMISSION_SET = EXTERNAL_ACCESS`, and if that doesn't work you can try `UNSAFE`. However, if one is attempting to dynamically load an Assembly, then that is supposed to be forbidden even for Assemblies marked as `UNSAFE`.

Since the issue here is of wanting to include a set of rules, that could probably be done in another Assembly. Then the main Assembly can reference the one containing the rules, and you just load the one containing the rules into SQL Server first. This would allow both Assemblies to remain marked as `SAFE`.

Of course, if there is no pressing need to keep the rules separate, then you could also just place them directly into a Collection in a Class.

Comment: Meanwhile I placed the rules in another assembly, but this did not fix the problem. I found your articles on SQL Server Central concerning SQLCLR. I will go through that in order to really understand how security is working in CLR functions. If not I leave a messsage here ;)

Comment: @MarcusBelz If the problem still existed, then you probably just move the serialized part? I was suggesting to get rid of the serialization entirely, and just put the Collection of rules itself in the other Assembly. There should not be any possible way to get an access violation from that; it would just be a simple reference.

Comment: Yes, I got that wrong.  I just moved the serialized part. The use case behind the complete story is to get get a more or less configurale phonetic translation for more than a million words persisted in the database allowing for a fast phonetic search. In total there are about 1000 rules that must be deserialized with every call to that function. In terms of performance, adding the rules directly in the code as a collection would be probably the preferable way. I will give it a try.

Comment: @MarcusBelz Since the rules don't change (at least, not without replacing the Assembly containing them), then you can instantiate them as a readonly static class variable. That will allow them to stay in memory and not need to be loaded per each call :-). Marking it as `readonly` will allow it to work in a `SAFE` Assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I did an undo on evreything except the constructor part (private/public). With or without signing the assembly I get the following message (10327):

> CREATE ASSEMBLY for assembly 'phonet42n.Core' failed because assembly
>   'phonet42n.Core' is not authorized for PERMISSION_SET =
>   EXTERNAL_ACCESS. The assembly is authorized when either of the
>   following is true: the database owner (DBO) has EXTERNAL ACCESS
>   ASSEMBLY permission and the database has the TRUSTWORTHY database
>   property on; or the assembly is signed with a certificate or an
>   asymmetric key that has a corresponding login with EXTERNAL ACCESS
>   ASSEMBLY permission.

Unfortunately I'm not familiar with signing an assembly: I just checked the checkbox in the property pages of the project properties:

[image: screenshot]

Don't know whether additional steps are missing.

Anyhow, as suggested in the message I then tried to create an asymmetric key using the following statements:

```
USE master; 
GO  

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[syslogins] WHERE [sid] = SUSER_SID('SQLCLRTestLogin'))
   BEGIN
      PRINT 'Dropping Login...'
      DROP LOGIN [SQLCLRTestLogin]
      PRINT 'End'
   END

GO
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [sys].[asymmetric_keys] WHERE [name] = 'SQLCLRTestKey')
   BEGIN
      PRINT 'Dropping Asymmetric Key...'
      DROP ASYMMETRIC KEY [SQLCLRTestKey]
      PRINT 'End'
   END
GO

BEGIN
   PRINT 'Creating Login...'
   CREATE ASYMMETRIC KEY [SQLCLRTestKey] FROM EXECUTABLE FILE = 'D:\phonet42n.net\Core\bin\Debug\phonet42n.Core.dll' 
   PRINT 'End'

   PRINT 'Creating Asymmetric Key...'
   CREATE LOGIN [SQLCLRTestLogin] FROM ASYMMETRIC KEY [SQLCLRTestKey]   
   PRINT 'End'

   PRINT 'Granting Access...'
   GRANT EXTERNAL ACCESS ASSEMBLY TO [SQLCLRTestLogin]; 
   PRINT 'End'
END
GO
```

In case of a **signed assembly** these statements succeed, whereas in case of an **unsigned assembly** I get the following Error message (15208):

> The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file does not exist or
>   has invalid format.

By the way.. don't know whether this matters. The target .NET Framework aof the assemly is 4.5. Finally... coming to the initial error message: [Adwaenyth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4346664/adwaenyth) was right with the missing public default construtor. The message was so far misleading, as the missing constructor does not affect the registrion of the assembly. You get the message only after a successfull registration at runtime, when making a call for the function phonet42n.

I really don't know, whether this is the solution by design. And I cannot not tell whether I opend the door with that for any potential threads.

I just can emphasize the the [Stairway series articles](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/105855/) especially on on SQLCLR. Excellent! It helps to get a understanding how SQLCLR works and what it is good for.

And (really) finally: the overall outcome for me is, that I will extract the rules from the XML and put load them directly by populating a collection as suggested by [srutzky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/577765/srutzky). Will be probably much more performant.

Comment: Thanks for those compliments :). The signing of the Assembly shouldn't have had anything to do with your issue. It only allows you to set the Assembly to `EXTERNAL_ACCESS` _without_ needing to set the Database to `TRUSTWORTHY ON` (which is a good thing!). So far I do not believe that the Access Violation error was misleading. The parameterless constructor _was_ missing (why it needs it is another issue). It would be interesting to see if you could add the constructor, set the Assembly (with embedded resource) to `SAFE`, and try the original deserialization. Still, static collection is fastest.